# Is this method thread safe?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, static, thread-safety, unity-container

I'm using MVC2 framework and Unity2 as the IOC container. I resolve an IHttpContextLocatorService instance using Unity as below.

```
  RootContainer.RegisterType<IHttpContextLocatorService, HttpContextLocatorService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

The above gives me a "singleton" of HttpContextLocatorService.

GetCurrentContext() function has been called by many places within our application. I'm concerned that GetCurrentContext() is not thread safety. It is not easy to test this as I cannot recreate multiple threads consists of various RequestContext and Controller etc.

Can anyone please advice whether the method "GetCurrentContext()" is thread safety?

```
public class HttpContextLocatorService : IHttpContextLocatorService
{

    [Dependency]
    public IControllerLocatorService ControllerLocator { get; set; }


    [Dependency]
    public IRequestContextLocatorService RequestContextLocator { get; set; }

    public HttpContextBase GetCurrentContext()
    {
        Controller controller = null;

        try
        {
            controller = this.ControllerLocator.GetController(this.RequestContextLocator.GetCurrentRequestContext()) as Controller;
        }
        catch { }

        if (controller == null)
        {
            return new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        }

        return controller.HttpContext;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's thread-safe if both implementations of `IControllerLocatorService.GetController()` and `RequestContextLocator.GetCurrentRequestContext()` are.

If they are stateful they (and your method by consequence) could be not thread-safe.
IMO you have 2 options:

- ensure that both those methods are thread-safe
- make the `GetCurrentContext` method thread-safe locking access to the two dependencies

Comment: I certainly agree. Your answer made my self a lot clearer. IControllerLocatorService and IRequestContextLocatorService  are not singleton. They create objects per request. So RequestContextLocator.GetCurrentRequestContext() and IControllerLocatorService.GetController() are thread safe. So this method is thread safe. Thanks :)